# Is that possible to have a conditional setter, more than 0 value?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

How to assign a setter to a conditional value such as more than `0`? I need to hide an object if the value will be not `0`. What would be the best way to do it? Any ideas are highly appreciated.

XAML example of `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Role.Count}" Value="0">
    <Setter TargetName="Counts" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a value converter, say `IsGreaterThanZero`, then write your XAML as,

```
<Window.Resources>
         <local:IsGreaterThanZero x:Key="isGreaterThanZero"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Role.Count, Converter={StaticResource isGreaterThanZero}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Counts" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

And IsGreaterThanZero can be written as,

```
public class IsGreaterThanZero: IValueConverter
{ 
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Int32.Parse(value as string) > 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException() ;//"PresenterConverter.ConvertBack() is not implemented!");
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Comment: @vladc77: Hope you know what "local" means in the XAML; it's just name namespace alias of your project where you define the value converter!

Comment: Yes, I do know. Thank you again.