# How to hide control if value is 0?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In xaml it was possible to handle controls' appearance using [DataTemplate.Triger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799918/is-that-possible-to-have-a-conditional-setter-more-than-0-value) but in win8 xaml it is not available:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Role.Count, Converter={StaticResource isGreaterThanZero}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Counts" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

How to do the same thing in windows 8 xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the default Visual Studio Templates for Grid and Split layouts, you will find an example of a value converter that sets a controls visibility based on a Boolean value.  The code is shown here

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

All you would need to is copy this code and modify it to set the visibility property based on an integer value - IntToVisibilityConverter, for example.  You would use the converter like this on the control you wanted to be affected

```
Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}}"
```